# WooCommerce Hide Price for only certain categories

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

So I have been struggling with this stupid woocommerce site that uses a plugin called "TM extra product options" - this messes with facebook product sync meaning I have to run duplicate products. (The client is too cheap to pay for the features to be built correctly).

I have been toying with functions snippets and css which is proving tedious. How do I hide price and variations for only certain categories?